# Arrays.binarysearch(double[]array, key) returning -1

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I have written a small piece of code to determine the index of the next smaller element in an array. The snippet of code is below:

```
public static int FindNextSmallest(double[] arr1, int current_small_index) {
    double current_smallest_element = arr1[current_small_index];       

    double[] new_arr1 = arr1.clone();

    Arrays.sort(new_arr1);

    int v = Arrays.binarySearch(new_arr1, current_smallest_element);

    double next_small = new_arr1[v + 1];
    int next_small_index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr1, next_small);
    return next_small_index;
}
```

The array contains the values: {0.6666,0.6666,0.6666,-0.9333,-0.9333}.

At the beginning, the current_small_index is 3 with current_small_element=-0.9333, Next it returns the next smallest element, which in this case is -0.9333 in the index position 4. But it returns -1.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

In this statement

```
int next_small_index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr1, next_small);
```

You are attempting to apply `binarySearch` to your original unsorted array.
The binary search method only works on sorted arrays.

Comment: I just see new_arr1 for sorting in question?

Comment: oh the next one sorry

Comment: Thank you @David sir. I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this with sorting and binary search, which is `O(n log n)` in time and `O(n)` in storage. You can do it in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` storage, working directly on the input array:

```
int next_smallest_index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
  if (i == current_smallest_index) continue;

  if (arr1[i] >= arr1[current_smallest_index]) {
    if (next_smallest_index == -1 || arr1[i] < arr1[next_smallest_index]) {
      next_smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, this gives you the index of the element directly: if you have sorted the list, you have lost ordering information, so you need to go back and search for an element with the value you found.